# Do you have to use display to output stuff using r6rs?

Tags: scheme, r6rs, r5rs

Background: I am new to scheme, and am using DrScheme to write my programs.

The following program outputs 12345 when I run the program as r5rs:

```
12345
```

However the following program outputs nothing (it's an r6rs program):

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

12345
```

That being said, I can get it to output 12345 by doing this:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(display 1235)
```

Is that something new with r6rs, where output only occurs when specifically specified using `display`? Or am I just doing something else wrong

Comment: a bare constant should not automatically print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subtle issue that you're seeing here.  In PLT, the preferred mode of operation is to write code in a module, where each module has a specification of the language it is written it.  Usually, the default language is `#lang scheme` (and `#!` is short for `#lang`).  In this language, the behavior is for all toplevel non-definition expressions to display their values (unless they're void -- as in the result of most side-effects).  But the `#lang r5rs` and `#lang r6rs` don't do the same -- so these toplevel expressions are evaluated but never displayed.

The reason you *did* see some output with the R5RS language is that you didn't use it as a "module" (as in `#lang r5rs`), but instead used the specific R5RS "language level".  This language level is more compatible to the R5RS, but for various subtle reasons this is not a good idea in general.  Using `#lang` is therefore generally better, and if you want to save yourself some additional redundant headaches, it'll be easier if you stick with `#lang scheme` for now, and worry about standards later.  (But YMMV, of course.)